# Android more accurate locating

Tags: android, geolocation

The image below shows the results of a location tracking exercise. I just wonder if it's possible to to make the location results android generates much more accurate?

For instance, is it possible to get the locations to follow the streets more accurately?

My location manager detects new locations by the following code:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 30000, 1, this);
```

And in my manifest, I am using **android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION**

[image]

Comment: Which device are you using? This chipset is really off.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the provider which you are using, you can iterate over all providers and select the one which has best accuracy, The following link has some insights in to how to perform location updates.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FhsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29